# Has CKAN been used as a data portal for any Open Science initiatives by an academic institution?

Tags: data-portal

CKAN is the leading data portal solution, and is typically used by governments and their agencies. I am wondering if this software has been used by scientific institutions and universities for Open Science projects. Links to example sites and/or relevant publications would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of any specific Open Science initiative, but looking at the organizations on datahub.io, just in the first page of results, I see two or three academic organizations posting.
[datahub organizations](https://datahub.io/organization)
Also, search for [science on datahub.io](https://datahub.io/dataset?q=science)